# Как применять условие, если в базе данных нету столбца? c#

Tags: c#, sql

Я заучиваю базу данных SQLite на c#. Мне нужна помощь. Как сделать проверку - когда нету столбца(например с `login`, то выводить `label1.text = "Такого пользователь нету!"`)

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!File.Exists(@"F:\c#Learn\DataBaseAndUILearn\logining\login\login\logins.db"))
            {
                SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(@"F:\c#Learn\DataBaseAndUILearn\logining\login\login\logins.db");
            }
            using (SQLiteConnection Connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = F:\c#Learn\DataBaseAndUILearn\logining\login\login\logins.db"))
            {
                string commandDb = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [user](" +
                    "[login] TEXT," +
                    "[password] TEXT)";
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(commandDb, Connect);
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string logins = $"SELECT [login] FROM [user] WHERE [login] = '{loginInput.Text}'";
            using (SQLiteConnection Connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = F:\c#Learn\DataBaseAndUILearn\logining\login\login\logins.db"))
            {
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(logins, Connect);
                command.Connection.Open();
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    label1.Text = "Добро пожаловать," + reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

UPD

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string logins = $"SELECT [login] FROM [user] WHERE [login] = '{loginInput.Text}'";
            using (SQLiteConnection Connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = F:\c#Learn\DataBaseAndUILearn\logining\login\login\logins.db"))
            {
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(logins, Connect);
                command.Connection.Open();
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string userName = reader.GetString(0);
                    label1.Text = userName;
                    if (userName == null)
                    {
                        label1.Text = "test";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label1.Text = "Добро пожаловать," + reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: попробуйте получить юзера, если вернет null/ошибку - значит такого юзера нет

Comment: @Aarnihauta ошибки нет, а null не могу определить, какая переменная должна получить. Command пробовал\

Comment: Вот вы используете `reader.GetString(0)`, если это вернет `null`, значит такого юзера нет. Переделайте код: `string userName = reader.GetString(0)` -> `if(userName == null)` ...

Comment: @Aarnihauta добавил код снизу. Не срабатывает. Кстати говоря `label1.Text = userName;` даже не активируется. Какой был текст, такой остался. else работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если запрос не вернул ни одной строки, то `reader.Read()` вернёт `false` Именно это и нужно проверять.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string logins = $"SELECT [login] FROM [user] WHERE [login] = '{loginInput.Text}'";
            using (SQLiteConnection Connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = F:\c#Learn\DataBaseAndUILearn\logining\login\login\logins.db"))
            {
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(logins, Connect);
                command.Connection.Open();
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    string userName = reader.GetString(0);
                    label1.Text = "Добро пожаловать," + userName;
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "Пользователь не найден";
                }
            }
        }
```